# Jupyter load dataframe into DB2 table

Tags: dataframe, jupyter-notebook, db2, sql-insert

I have a Jupyter notebook and I am trying to read CSV files from URLS and then load them in a DB2. My first problem is that sometimes the table exists and I need to drop it first - second, seems impossible to load the data into tables.. what am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi
```

After this I try

```
dsn = "DRIVER={{IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER}};" + \
      "DATABASE=BLUDB;" + \
      "HOSTNAME=myhostname;" + \
      "PORT=50000;" + \
      "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;" + \
      "UID=myuid;" + \
      "PWD=mypassword;"

    url1="https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/05c3415cbfbtfnr2fx4atenb2sd361ze.csv"
    s1=requests.get(url1).content
    df1=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s1.decode('utf-8')))
    url2="https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/f9gjvj1gjmxxzycdhplzt01qtz0s7ew7.csv"
    s2=requests.get(url2).content
    df2=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s2.decode('utf-8')))
    url3="https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/svflyugsr9zbqy5bmowgswqemfpm1x7f.csv"
    s3=requests.get(url3).content
    df3=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s3.decode('utf-8')))
```

all works. And connection as well

```
hdbc  = ibm_db.connect(dsn, "", "")
hdbi = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(hdbc)
```

and this fails

```
#DropTableIfExists = ibm_db.exec_immediate(hdbc, 'DROP TABLE QBG03137.DATAFRAME1')

CreateTable = ibm_db.exec_immediate(hdbc, sql)
resultSet = ibm_db.exec_immediate(hdbc, sql)

#define row and fetch tuple
row = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(resultSet)
comma = ""
while (row != False):
    for column in row:
        print(comma,end="")
        print(column,end="")
        comma = ","
    print()
    row = ibm_db.fetch_tuple(resultSet)
```

With error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-94-840854e92bd7> in <module>
      5 
      6 # Testing table exists
----> 7 resultSet = ibm_db.exec_immediate(hdbc, sql)
      8 
      9 #define row and fetch tuple

Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0601N  The name of the object to be created is identical to the existing name "QBG03137.DATAFRAME1" of type "TABLE".  SQLSTATE=42710 SQLCODE=-601
```

Comment: You don't show all the code, e.g., what is the SQL statement to be executed. The error says that the object exists.

Comment: Thank you very much for having a look in this. This is the whole code. I haven't execute any SQL statement yet, I couldn't load the data in the table (even if I drop the table and execute, I don't know how to load the dataframe data INTO the table, that is, how do I do INSERT)

Comment: Spend some time studying the pandas documentation so that you have a basic comprehension of how pandas can be used (e.g. the .to_sql method). Your question shows symptom SQL0601N which means you tried to create a table that already exists. Learn from the Db2-documentation how to either DROP an existing table, or use `truncate table` if applicable, or if your Db2-on-cloud service runs Db2 v11.5 or higher then you can use `create table if not exists ...`. Stackoverflow is not a substitute for education.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957641/insert-into-db2-table-from-a-python-dataframe ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert into DB2 table from a python dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44957641/insert-into-db2-table-from-a-python-dataframe)